# How to reset the app after the midnight

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on `Pedometer` application via using `CMPedometer` Class. It works fine and I cross-checked the value via built in app- `HealthKit`. However, when I wake up this morning and I was still seeing the yesterday value.

Then I killed the app and reopened it again, then it showed me today value.

My question is how to handle this issue?

Comment: When the app becomes active, you may want to `queryPedometerDataFromDate:toDate:withHandler:` again starting today?

Comment: Could you please give an example rather than as a comment? I am using that method, but it does not restart when I open the app in the morning unless I kill the app then restart it. Actually I have a label that shows the number of steps that user walked. This needs to be updated.

Comment: Learn about App Life Cycle: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/

Answer (score 1):

you can use applicationWillEnterForeground Delegate in your ViewController or Model ...
( if you want handle in specific VC or model you must register it ) or you can use this Delegate from your appDelegate

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateData) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]]; // Dont forgot about removeObserve 

 -(void)updateData{

[[CMPedometer sharedInstance]update]; // update your data

// now you should update Your UI 

[self.tableView reloadData];}
```